# CSS required for transparent BG and normal text in Revolution Slider -- Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website where I need to create a slider that has text over a transparent black background. An example is http://playbaseballincentralamerica.com/. Here is the css that I am using along with the revolution slider plugin:

```
position: absolute; 
color: #fff; 
text-shadow: none; 
font-weight: 800; 
font-size: 60px; 
line-height: 60px; 
font-family: Arial; 
margin: 0px; 
border-width: 0px; 
border-style: none; 
white-space:nowrap; 
padding: 0px 4px; 
padding-top: 1px;   
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
visibility: visible;
```

So I have tried the following as well:

```
background-color: black;
background-color: transparent;
```

I have copied the css from the http://playbaseballincentralamerica.com/ because I have access to it, and it doesn't work. So what I am thinking is that maybe there is a div tag or something that has all the backgrounds as transparent. But I don't know where or how it works... Can anyone help me out? I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Please give us a fiddle of your code. It will be very helpful, and I doubt many of us will look at the source code on the site you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` has a `class` called `tp-caption very_big_white` with the following CSS:

```
.tp-caption.very_big_white {
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

You can add a class to your div with the same properties to achieve the effect you want.